# Unable to get data from firebase to my html page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Basically I want to display data from my firebase account to my html div element but I'm unable to do so as the div remains blank.
I'm a beginner to firebase and javascript so please bear with me.
here is the code I've written.

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p>Just DO it!</p>  
    <div id="box">
        <div class="box-top">Bookings</div>
        <div class="box-panel">
            <script>

                var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com");
                ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                  console.log(snapshot.key());
                  document.write(snapshot.key());
                });

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the screenshot of my firebase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyWYZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are printing the key for the root node which is null. You can print the key for a child node such as the `/days`.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days");
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
    document.write(snapshot.key());
});
```

For the sake of demo, you could iterate the object properties using javascript's for in loop.

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
  var data = snapshot.val();
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      document.write(data[key].name + "<br>");
    };
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhn139ep/

Access child nodes using nested loops. See JSFiddle for update.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhn139ep/3/

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days");
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

var data = snapshot.val();

//Show Days of week.
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        document.write(data[key].name + "<br>");
    };
}
document.write('<br><br>');

//Show Slots for each day of week using a nested for in loop.
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var slots = data[key].slots;
        var dayOfWeek = data[key].name;

        for (var slotKey in slots) {
            if (slots.hasOwnProperty(slotKey)) {

                //Get an individual slot.
                var slot = slots[slotKey];

                console.log(slot);
                document.write('Day of week: ' + dayOfWeek + '<br>');
                document.write('Slot Time: ' + slot.time + '<br>');
                document.write('Booked: ' + slot.booked + '<br>');
                document.write('<hr>');
            }
        }                              
    }
}

//Access data within a node directly.
console.log(data['monday'].name); //Prints Monday.
console.log(data['tuesday']['slots']['72'].booked); //prints false.
console.log(data.tuesday.slots['72'].booked); //prints false.

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply Gregg.
Please bear with me a little longer. 
in the for loop, what do you mean by the var key in data 
P.S its not working :/

Comment: I am using the [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to loop through all key value pairs. Have you tried the JS fiddle?

Comment: To extract the data from firebase queries, you can use the for in loop to iterate through the values (such as Monday, Tuesday, etc). This is what the jsFiddle demonstrates. Are you able to achieve your goal using the examples provided?

Comment: Yes Gregg im almost there 
what if im trying to access the childs of my key like childs of the key name? 
what would i write then ?

Comment: You will need to familiarize yourself with bracket notation when working with objects. Please see this resource: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Comment: just saw the updated jsFiddle version 
Thanks a bunch Gregg 
the data is displayed now! 
Thankyou !

Comment: Great to hear! I forgot to mention you can also access data directly using 'dot notation' with the exception of keys that have numbers (72, 900). `data.tuesday.slots['72'].booked`.

Comment: a slight problem gregg, once the page gets the data from firebase,
it populates the entire page instead of just the div i want it into..

Comment: Can you create a JS Fiddle to show what you have coded so far?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle that does some DOM manipulation to iterate the records. I believe it could be close to your objectives. https://jsfiddle.net/bhn139ep/4/

Comment: I tried this code snippet with my firebase db (android), but it's not working. Is there any way to show my DB content from my android project in HTML?